# CFA in R (lavaan) with ordinal data - polychoric correlation included?

Tags: r, estimation, ordinal, factor-analysis, r-lavaan

I would like to compute a confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) with ordinal data in `R` using `lavaan`. The data is from a questionnaire, containing 16 items structured on a Likert-scale.

I assume a 4-factor-model to be the best fit to my data. To compute the CFA I searched for information and found some useful advise in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/7489589_Comparison_of_alternative_estimation_methods_in_confirmatory_factor_analyses_of_the_General_Health_Questionnaire).

The recommendation is to use DWLS-estimation and polychoric correlation. I've managed to compute the CFA with DWLS in `R` using the `lavaan` package. I found out that in M*plus* the DWLS estimation, or WLSMV which is the same, uses [polychoric correlation](http://web.pdx.edu/~newsomj/semclass/ho_estimate.pd) , unfortunately I never used M*plus* and would like to work with `R`, so I was wondering if in `lavaan` it's the same.

So far I computed the CFA like this:

I specified a model (model.4) with 4 factors (AV, AW, AB, AA), (each factor has 4 items)

```
model.4='
AV =~ AVf1_+AVf2+AVf3+AVf4 
AW =~ AWf1+AW2+AWf3+AWf4 
AB =~ ABf1+ABf2+ABf3+ABf4 
AA =~ AAf1+AAf2+AAf3+AAf4'
```

Then I used the `"ordered"` function because of my ordered data, which is recommended in the `lavaan` package

```
model.ord = cfa(model.4,data=Data,ordered=c(
"AVf1","AVf2","AVf3","AVf4",
"AWf1","AWf2","AWf3","AWf4",
"ABf1","ABf2","ABf3","ABf4",
"AAf1","AAf2","AAf3","AAf4"))
```

This worked well. I got an output with all the relevant fit-indices (CFI, RMSEA etc.). Now my question is, if this automatically based upon polychoric correlation like in M*plus*? If it's not - how can I add a command to use polychoric correlation? There is some information in the `lavaan` package about polychoric correlation, `lavCor`, but I don't know if it's useful for my problem and unfortunately I don't know how to use it.

I tried like this:

```
model.ord1 <- lavCor(cfa(model.4,data=Data,ordered=c(
 "AVf1","AVf2","AVf3","AVf4",
"AWf1","AWf2","AWf3","AWf4",
"ABf1","ABf2","ABf3","ABf4",
"AAf1","AAf2","AAf3","AAf4"))
```

))

But `> summary(model.ord1, fit=T)` didn't work. I did not receive any results.

**To sum up**: Is my CFA automatically based upon polychoric correlation? If not, how can I change my function to implement polychoric correlation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link contains a similar use case I guess: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/structural-equation-modeling-and-confirmatory-factor-analysis - scroll down to: "The lavaan syntax":

With the argument `ordered = c`, which you have used, you have told lavaan that some variables are ordinal in nature. In response, lavaan estimates polychoric correlations for these variables.

But I don't know if its true/correct. Can anybody confirm it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [according to folks in the lavaan user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/lavaan/kdbSKNRDiYg/BdIs96nXDgAJ), using the "ordered" option will use DWLS with polychoric correlations for the ordinal variables.

You can double check this by comparing the output of

```
inspect(fit, "sampstat")$cov
```

where fit is the output of a cfa() model with ordered variables, and

```
lavCor(fit, ordered = TRUE, group = NULL, output = "cor")
```

which reports polychoric correlations